# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception with orcale19c

Tags: oracle, authentication, passwords, oracle19c

I am facing this issue in oracle19c.
I have added the following to sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8
```

as well as

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

But I am getting:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password: logon denied
```

I read all over stackoverflow to re-create the password. 
I have even tried creating password file as well as changing the password of the user by alter command.

**Can any one help me out with the exact steps to re-create password.**

Comment: Why application and version do you use to connect to the database?

Comment: I am trying to connect my web app, which has perl DBD 1.7 with oracle 19c database.

Comment: Which Oracle client version is installed? Or does the perl DBD runs also on the database server?

Comment: right DBD is also on same server

Answer (score 0):

You can create a password file using `orapwd` utility.

Users are added to the password file when they are granted the SYSDBA, SYSOPER, SYSASM, SYSKM, SYSDG or SYSBACKUP privilege.

By default, SYS is the only user that has SYSDBA and SYSOPER privileges. Creating a password file via `orapwd` enables the remote users to connect with admin privileges.

The basic command to create the password file is

```
orapwd file=<Password file name> entries=<nnumber of entries allowed> force=<y/n>
```

There should be no space around `=`.

Here, You should use `force=y` to permits overwriting an existing password file.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, so I did `orapwd file=newpassword entries=10 force=y format=12`  on folder `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ `. Then I executed `grant sysdba to user;`  tried logging with user works fine, but my web application still shows logon denied. I restarted the lsnrctl as well the machine itself. Any step am I missing out? I did not delete the previous password file.